# Is it correct to say "my child likes to swing / dangle / hang from my hands" in this case?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

As shown in the picture, my son often lets his body hang freely by holding my hands. His weight thus pulls my hands down and I feel like I am lifting a very heavy thing.

Is it correct to say "**my child likes to swing / dangle / hang from my hands**" in this case?

I am not sure if "**from**" is a correct word, can we say "**my child likes to swing / dangle / hang ob my hands**"?

Comment: dangle and hang do no imply **movement** necessarily. If you kid was dangling from a rope five feet off the ground, believe me, you'd be worried.

Comment: Actually, almost no children would be strong enough to be the "active" participant here - they'd almost always be completely dependent on Dad having a strong grip on their arms. So arguably it's more accurate to say *My child likes **me to swing / dangle him** by his arms* or similar. I don't know about other languages, but Anglophones would be much more likely to refer to ***arms*** rather than ***hands*** in contexts like this. And my guess is ***by*** would be much more common than ***from***.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I fail to see how a child can enjoy being dangled. Only swung.

Comment: @Lambie: [*Julia **dangled her son** in the shallows. The boy kicked, spraying himself in the face. His eyes opened wide, then **he chuckled and did it again**.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Julia+dangled+her+son+in+the+shallows%22)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of these are valid constructions, but they mean different things. To swing would imply that the child is moving back and forth. To hang implies that they are just holding still. To dangle often implies that the thing is not very securely attached, or in a dangerous or temporary situation, so it's probably the least likely word one would use here.

"From" is the correct preposition.

As a native speaker, and father of two small children, I would say that the most likely words I would use are "my child likes it when I let him hang from my hands", to emphasize that I'm doing the work. Or "my child likes it when I swing him while I hold his hands".

But those are more complex sentences. "My child likes to hang from my hands" is pretty good because it leaves it ambiguous who is doing the work, and the listener will just assume it's you. Or "My child likes to hang from my hands and swing" does the same thing for a swinging action.